# Scala Slick - bi-directional mapping operator cannot be found

Tags: postgresql, scala, import, slick

Using the Slick version 3.1.1 [enter link description here][1]

[1]: http://slick.lightbend.com/download/ I want to create a projection that maps to the `case class` of mine. However, the problem I keep getting is that the operator for bi-directional mapping cannot be found. Here is a quick look onto the dependencies defined in the .sbt file:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "com.typesafe.slick" %% "slick" % "3.1.1",
  "org.slf4j" % "slf4j-nop" % "1.6.4"
)
```

Whereas the case class and the Table[T] derivation I've defined are as follows:

```
import slick.driver.PostgresDriver._
import slick.lifted._

case class Log(created_at: String, file: String, line: String, systemName: String, systemVersion: String, networkStatus: Boolean, message: String)

class LogTable(tag: Tag) extends Table[Log](tag, "log") {
  def created_at = column[String]("created_at")
  def file = column[String]("file")
  def line = column[String]("line")
  def systemName = column[String]("systemName")
  def systemVersion = column[String]("systemVersion")
  def networkStatus = column[Boolean]("networkStatus")
  def message = column[String]("message")

  def * = (created_at, file, line, systemName, systemVersion, networkStatus, message) <> (LogKitIOS.tupled, LogKitIOS.unapply _)
}
```

Does anyone have an idea onto why I am not able to use the `<> operator`?

Comment: 1. How does your error message look like?

2. You have provided the definition of `Log`, but you haven't provided the definition of `LogKitIOS`. Are they the same thing or there is something missing here?

Comment: That's probably the answer :D @dsafa you should probably use slick codegenerator to avoid manually writing all the boilerplate, and as a bonus it's bug free code !